# CSS scale transition ease-out not working (image is already scaled)

Tags: css

I have this element here:

```
<div class="item active">
                        <a href="/Awards">
                            <div class="fill awards-banner">
                            </div>
                            <div class="container awards-banner-text">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <img src="~/Images/banner-images/banner-text-01.png?v=656546" alt="Awards" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

and I am trying to get the background image to scale using transform ease-out, but instead of easing into the scale, it just does the scale, an transform at all, just goes into full scale, I hope this makes sense!

Here is my CSS:

```
#home .slider .fill.awards-banner {
    background-image:url('/Images/banner-images/banner-01.png');
    background-position: 0px;
    transition: all 50s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 50s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 50s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 50s ease;
  -o-transition: all 50s ease;
}

#home .slider .item.active .fill {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}
```

Comment: are you sure you understand how and **when** transition works ? ... you see the effect when you change the property but not when you initially set it

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I see the effect when you can change but not on init, how do I get it to work on init?

Comment: you have the answer :) it's logic, you have to setup a value then change it ... this is called animation, so use animation instead if transition or use JS to change the value to make the transition working

Comment: I tried this `animation: all 50s ease;
  -moz-animation: all 50s ease;
  -ms-animation: all 50s ease;
  -webkit-animation: all 50s ease;
  -o-animation: all 50s ease;` it did not work still

Comment: animation doesn't work like this ... read more about it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp